# AngularJS - ng-checked isn't triggering ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically I have a table and each row have a text input and a checkbox, the checkbox assign a default value to the input. The problem I'm having is that I want to have a checkbox to check all checkboxes, and I've done it, but it's not evaluating the expression in ngChange.

This is what I have:

**1) Controller.js:**

```
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.def_income = [];
$scope.master = false;
$scope.formData.income = [{ from:"", to:"", income:"" }]
$scope.addSal = function () {
    this.formData.income.push({from:'',to:'',income:''});
};
$scope.delSal = function (index) {
    if (index != 0) this.formData.income.splice(index,1);
}
$scope.masterToggle = function () {
    this.master = this.master ? false : true;
}
$scope.defIncome = function (index) {
    if (this.def_income[index]) this.formData.income[index].income="Default";
    else this.formData.income[index].income = "";
}
```

**2) index.html:**

```
<a href="" ng-click="addSal()">Add</a>
<a href="" ng-model="master" ng-click="masterToggle()">Check all</a>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Income</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="income in formData.income">
            <td><input kendo-date-picker class="form-control" ng-model="income.from" placeholder="From" /></td>
            <td><input kendo-date-picker class="form-control" ng-model="income.to" /></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="income.income" /></td>
            <td>Default income <input type="checkbox" ng-model="def_income[$index]" ng-checked="master" ng-change="defIncome($index)" /></td>
            <td><a href="" ng-show="$index != 0" ng-click="delSal($index)">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that when masterToggle function is executed, it effectively toggle the $scope.master value, and it's evaluated in ng-checked, the checkboxes are checked, but the defIncome function that should be evaluated when the checkbox value changes isn't.

Im really new to AngularJS (less than a week) so if I'm applying some bad practices please feel free to point them out :)

**UPDATE 1:**

So I followed embee's suggestion and it worked, I wonder if there's a better way, anyways, this is what I did:

```
$scope.masterToggle = function () {
    this.master = this.master ? false : true;
    for (var j = 0; j <= this.formData.salarios.length-1; j++) {
        this.formData.salarios[j].salario = $scope.master ? "Salario mínimo" : "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [ngChange docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange):

> Evaluate given expression when user changes the input. The expression
>   is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model.

In your case the value change is coming from the model, not when the user changes the input of the "default income" checkbox which you've put ng-change on, therefore the expression is not evaluated.

Comment: Ok, so it won't work since ngChange only evaluates the expression if the input comes from user interaction. How would yo do it? I have thought about $watch, but I'm not really sure how to implement it, and angular's documentation isn't very explanatory

Comment: Assuming you want defIncome to be called for every income in formdata.income, could you call it in the $scope.masterToggle after setting the value of scope.master?